# Const method to temporarily change object

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

I have a class `Reader` which provides access to a binary file to perform read operations on it.

This file contains several lists of offsets within the same file, where data is to be found. This means that, to get to certain data segments, one has to read an offset from some position, then jump to that offset, read an offset again, jump there, etc. until finally you reach the actual data.

The class maintains a reading position that is adjusted each time you call a method like

```
// reads 4 bytes and advances the position by 4 bytes
uint32 Reader::readOffset() { /* */ }
```

or

```
// moves the position to offset
void Reader::jumpTo(uint32 offset) { /* */ }
```

Those methods obviously cannot be `const` as they are moving the reading position.

For convenient navigation between several levels of the file, the class provides a stack, where one can push and pop offsets as needed:

```
uint32 someOffset = reader.readOffset();
reader.pushOffset(); // remember position
reader.jumpTo(someOffset); // do something on another position
reader.popOffset(); // go back to where we were before
```

Those push/pop methods cannot be `const` as well, because they alter the offset stack.

The problem now is with convenience methods, that are supposed to extract data from an internally known position within the file. They have to work regardless of the current reading position and should not touch it. By design, they ought to be `const`, but this does not work:

```
uint32 Reader::readSomeDataFromKnownLocation() const
{
    pushOffset();

    jumpTo(1234ul);
    uint32 data = readData();

    popOffset();

    return data;
}
```

I *do* know that this method will leave the object in the same state as it was before the call, but still I cannot make it `const` because each and every method I use within it is non-`const`.

So, my question is, what is the best approach when having to temporarily change an object's state within a "by-design" `const` method?

I thought about `const_cast<Reader*>(this)` but this seems like a hackish approach. Or do you think it is justified in this scenario?

Comment: if it's const by design, then it's a constant and shouldn't be changed. if it's gonna be changed,then it's not a constant.

Comment: The change is only happening internally and temporarily. The method will make sure the final object state on return is "identical" to what the user had before he invoked it. That's what I want to show by marking it `const`.

Comment: Not correct, you can't verify that it will happen. the code (or thread) can fail right after you've jumped ahead and read from the file. then the object itself is in a different state (Think multithreading with an evil thread killing other threads).

Comment: That is true. So you think saying it is `const` would just be some vague assumption and not really conforming to const-correctness? Is it best to just leave it non-const and only document that the object's state won't (shouldn't) be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the position field `mutable` and then mark your logically read only methods as `const`.

If you want to keep the `pushOffset` and `popOffset` methods in the public API, you should introduce private versions that are `const`, and use the private ones from within your `readSomeDataFromKnownLocation` method.

Comment: I cannot make the position `mutable` and the read methods `const` because they will yield different results for the user depending on the current position, plus they change the potential result for subsequent calls.

Comment: @Dienes I thought your read methods were restoring the position indicator after the read completes. If that's the case, how do they change the subsequent calls?

Comment: There are two kinds of read methods: One that will advance the reading position with each call, and one that do only temporarily move the reading position to retrieve data, but then restore the old position before returning. The latter depend on the former.

Comment: @Dienes Then to make the latter const, you will need to introduce private const versions of the former. It's possible -- I doubt you'll find having two versions of most of your methods to be worth having the readSpecificData() methods const.

Comment: I see. So in conclusion it is okay to just leave it non-`const` and communicate that it will not change the current reading position. Thanks.